SSIS Flat File Destination Cannot Open File
I have an SSIS 2019 package that has three separate lookup tasks and would like to send the no match rows to a flat file.
I would like to use one flat file instead of three, but I am getting an error message "Cannot open the file, it is being used by another process."
It seems I cannot have one flat file connection with three flat file connections all pointing to the same file.
Is there any way to use one file instead of three?
Thanks
